# Data Saver Mode - React Native

Tags: android, react-native, android-7.0-nougat

I build an app using react native v0.60. Receive a complain from user when they set their phone in **Data Saver** mode the app is cannot be used. The user need to enable the **Allow app while Data saver on** then only the app is accessible. Have any idea how to overcome this issue. Problem occurred in Android 7.

Comment: There could be multiple reasons of it. First check your application if it is performing any long running tasks like calling the APIs in background or anything that's running in background. The OS might have detected and marked your app as battery hungry.

Another reason, the user might have miscellaneously put your in some kind of blocked list for power saving mode.